# Is pressure the derivative of viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, dimensional-analysis, viscosity, si-units

I noticed the units for viscosity are $\left(\frac{kg}{m \cdot s}\right)$ and the units for pressure are $\left(\frac{kg}{m \cdot s^2}\right)$. Are these related in any way? Is there another relationship between viscosity and pressure I'm not seeing?

Comment: No.  There is no relation at all.  Pressure is a force per unit area and unrelated to any kind of viscosity.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: that could be turned into an answer

Comment: The units of torque & work are Newton * Length . But torque is not work & vice versa !

Comment: @KyleKanos ... did just that.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no relation at all. Pressure is a force per unit area and unrelated to any kind of viscosity.  The kind of relation you have in mind would suggest pressure is some sort of rate of change of viscosity, and this is just not the case.